# Enabling javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am facing some problems  in my web application I have some hidden fields, when I press f12 it will open developer tools and hidden fields are visible there, so I disabled the f12 using some javascript code snippet. But in IE if ithe javascript is not enabled then again same issue will happen.
So is there any way to enable the javascript in IE without manual settings(any programmatic way)?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you are trying to prevent people looking at your page through F12 dev tools, you can't. You should design your system so that it is secure, even if people can see the hidden mechanisms your pages use.

Comment: this is not possible ... and makes no sense anyway like Rory McCrossan said

Comment: what if someone opens it in Firefox and uses firebug? or uses chrome? point is you cannot prevent someone from modifying the html, you should make the application more secure at the server side

Comment: sorry guys.. for asking this stupid question.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot enable JavaScript in any browser programmatically. That would be just stupid thing to exist.

Think about you browsing to some malicious site filled with harmful JavaScript - even though you have set your JavaScript off in your browser to prevent the harmful scripts, the malicious site could programmatically enable it again.

Answer (score 1):

No thats not possible but

you could load your form-fields with some ajax

so if theres no js, the form fields are simply not there.
But that also means, that if theres no js, you dont have your correct form.

And do you really only want ie-f12-users not to see your form-fields ? what if someone uses firefox or chrome inspectors ... or just opens the source-code ? i dont get it